# Convert html foreach loop data to webgrid using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Below html table is filling using two loop condition, and same i want using two loop conditions to fill Webgrid

```
<table class="awe-ajaxlist table_dashboard">
    <tr class="tbl_header">
        <td>
            Payor
        </td>
        <td>
            Check #
        </td>
        <td>
            Billed Amount
        </td>
        <td>
            Paid Amount
        </td>
        <td>
            Check Date
        </td>
        <td>Download File</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var i in (List<MyDME.Data.Model.ERNFileRequestDTO>)ViewBag.lst)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo.Count; j++)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @i.Parse835Details.storedPayorName[j]
                </td>
                <td>
                    @i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo[j]
                </td>
                <td>
                    @i.Parse835Details.storedTotalBilled[j]

                </td>
                <td>
                    @i.Parse835Details.storedTotalPaid[j]

                </td>
                <td>
                     @(i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(4, 2) + "/" + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(6, 2) + "/" + i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j].Substring(0, 4))

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='/PatientManagement/DownloadUploadedDocument?fileName=@Html.Raw(i.path)'>Download</a>

                </td>
            </tr>


        }

    }
            </table>
```

I have tried to fill one field in web grid by using below code.

```
@{
      var grid2 = new WebGrid();
    List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    foreach (var i in (List<MyDME.Data.Model.ERNFileRequestDTO>)ViewBag.lst)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo.Count; j++)
        {
            cols.Add(grid2.Column("Payor", format:@<text> <span class="display-mode">@i.Parse835Details.storedPayorName[j]</span> </text>, style: "col1Width"));

        }
    }

}
```

when I am click debugging mode after code line complete on this line

```
var grid2 = new WebGrid();
```

the following error is showing.

[image]

Comment: *"i have tried webgrid inside forarch but its not working for me"* - Please show your attempt and describe the problem you encountered.

Comment: Could you pls explain what is "not working for me"?

Comment: Can you see now i have update question and added bounty also. @Serge

Comment: A bounty doesn't make your question answerable. Thinking about what it looks like in the eyes of complete strangers tends to be more fruitful. You still didn't clarify "not working for me". Errors in the debugger don't cut it, the debugger may show all kinds of errors that won't ever occur while running. What's relevant is what happens when you *run* the code and how that deviates from what *should* happen.

Comment: i am not getting what is not understandable in my question, i need to convert into webgrid and also i have told what i have tried that is correct. @GertArnold

Comment: nice some one is asking what is web-grid.

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan Did you do any kind of research on how to use a WebGrid before asking this question? This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: using multiple for-each dont know brother. @Nkosi

Comment: can any one explain what is not understandable to you all. @Nkosi

Comment: What is the actual error message. These are the kind of details that we need to help diagnose the problem. The image shown provides no useful information.

Comment: No need to get angry at me I am trying to understand the actual issue. You have the actual code, we don't. So on till the problem is clarified not much help can be provided. Putting a high bounty on the question will definitely bring more attention to it, but wont have the effect you want if the details are not sufficient.

Comment: can you come to my chat. @Nkosi

Comment: I avoid chats because they end up with unnecessary back and forth, wasting time. Edit your post with the relevant details and we can go from there.

Comment: Question is clear why you people want more clarification on this question, wait i will update answer once i will get from my end, i will post answer very soon. @Nkosi

Comment: You can't instantiate WebGrid with empty constructor. Why? Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webgrid?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2).

Comment: @MaciejLos OMG, is that all? If only OP had shown the *runtime* error instead of a debugger screenshot. What a waste of time and rep.

Comment: @GertArnold, i'm not completely sure, but it seems that's all. :) It depends on runtime error.

Comment: @MaciejLos all the constructor parameters are [**optional**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webgrid.-ctor?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_Helpers_WebGrid__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Object__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__System_String_System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_), so technically you can instantiate it with empty constructor, but again OP prefers not to provide relevant details so we are left guessing

Comment: @Nkosi, agree. Note, that OP didn't show complete error message. So, this is my best guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptions you've included in your question are happening because you have not bound the WebGrid to a data source. You also don't appear to have code that would spit out the table, so that would explain why you wouldn't see any output  from the table if that's also an issue.

If you want to use `WebGrid` to display your data, you are going to have a much easier time if you simplify your objects first. I think the structure you're working with is too complex/disconnected for it and made this a much more complicated problem than it should be.

It looks like you're working with a structure something along these lines:

```cs
public class ERNFileRequestDTO
{
    public ParsedRecords Parse835Details { get; set; }
}

public class ParsedRecords
{
    public List<string> storedPayorName { get; set; }
    public List<string> storedChkNo { get; set; }
    public List<string> storedTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public List<string> storedTotalPaid { get; set; }
    public List<string> storedChkDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> path { get; set; }
}
```

`WebGrid` is expecting a flat object more like this:

```cs
public class ConsolidatedRecordForDisplay
{
    public string storedPayorName { get; set; }
    public string storedChkNo { get; set; }
    public string storedTotalBilled { get; set; }
    public string storedTotalPaid { get; set; }
    public string storedChkDate { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

I made up a dataset that matches the structure you've described (though IMO parsing these as rows instead of columns from the original source would make more sense than transforming it just for display):

```cs
var raw = new List<ERNFileRequestDTO>
{
    new ERNFileRequestDTO {
        Parse835Details = new ParsedRecords {
            storedPayorName = new List<string> {"bob", "jane", "john", "jill"},
            storedChkNo = new List<string> {"1","2","3","4" },
            storedChkDate = new List<string> { "20210625","20210624","20210623","20210622" },
            storedTotalBilled = new List<string> { "$500", "$600", "$700", "$800" },
            storedTotalPaid = new List<string> { "$500", "$501", "$700", "$0" },
            path = new List<string>{"file1.pdf", "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf", "file4.pdf"}
        }
    }
};
```

You can get to the flattened data model by doing the same style of nested looping you're already doing:

```cs
ViewBag.lst = new List<ConsolidatedRecordForDisplay>();
foreach(var i in raw)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo.Count; j++)
    {
        ViewBag.lst.Add(new ConsolidatedRecordForDisplay
        {
            storedChkDate = i.Parse835Details.storedChkDate[j],
            storedChkNo = i.Parse835Details.storedChkNo[j],
            storedPayorName = i.Parse835Details.storedPayorName[j],
            storedTotalBilled = i.Parse835Details.storedTotalBilled[j],
            storedTotalPaid = i.Parse835Details.storedTotalPaid[j],
            path = i.Parse835Details.path[j]
        });
    }
}
```

And then display it using more appropriately simple view logic like this:

```cs
@{
    var grid2 = new WebGrid(ViewBag.lst);
}
@grid2.GetHtml(
    columns: grid2.Columns(
                grid2.Column("storedPayorName", "Payor"),
                grid2.Column("storedChkNo", "Check #"),
                grid2.Column("storedTotalBilled", "Billed Amount"),
                grid2.Column("storedTotalPaid", "Paid Amount"),
                grid2.Column("storedChkDate", "Check Date", @<text>@item.storedChkDate.Substring(4, 2)/@item.storedChkDate.Substring(6, 2)/@item.storedChkDate.Substring(0, 4)</text>),
                grid2.Column("path", "Download File", @<text><a href='/PatientManagement/DownloadUploadedDocument?fileName=@Html.Raw(@item.path)'>Download</a></text>)
))
```